# Cycle in a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

My code needs to find a cycle in a linked list. If there is a cycle then the output is `1`; the result is `0` otherwise. I've done research and learnt about Floyd's cycle algorithm and came across several other posts that contain the code for the algorithm. But I'm failing some test cases here on HackerRank. Could smb please tell me what is wrong with the code? Thanks!

```
int HasCycle(Node head) {
    if(head == null){
        return 0;
    }
    Node slow = head;
    Node fast = head;

    while(true)
    {
        slow = slow.next;
        if(fast.next != null){
            fast = fast.next.next;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
        if(slow == null || fast == null){
             return 0;
        }
        if(slow.data == fast.data){
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you making this return an `int`, instead of a `boolean`, which would be the natural choice for answering a yes/no question such as "does this have a cycle?"?

Comment: I assume `slow.data == fast.data` should be replaced by `equals()` or Apache's `objectEqual()` unless data is a primitive type.

Comment: the issue, as in my answer is that even if slow.data==fast.data, that does not mean it is the same node!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is when a linked list has .data fields with all 10 for example. Then it always is a cycle according to your algo. You need if slow==fast return 1 as opposed to if slow.data==fast.data.